# Python - How do I match this pattern (number/number) with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get my head around the regex module in python.  I tried to get my program to match the following pattern from a line of text that the user inputs:

a number between 8-13 "/" a number between 0-15

For example: 8/2, 11/13, 10/9, etc.

The pattern that I came up with was:

`upstream = re.compile(r'[8-9|1[0-3][/][0-9|1[0-5]')`

However, this regex works with mixed results:

```
Enter a slot/port : 8/2    
['8/2']                    # This is correct

Enter a slot/port : 1/0    
['1/0']                    # This should print the "else" statement

Enter a slot/port : 8/15
['8/1']                    # The output is incomplete
```

The problem seems to stem from the forward slash, but I am not sure.  I do know that I need some assistance in solving this issue.  If anyone can help me solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

The complete script is below.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[8-9|1[0-3][/][0-9|1[0-5]')

upstream = input("Enter a slot/port : ")

if re.search((pattern), upstream):
    print(re.findall(pattern, upstream))
else:
    print("We have a problem")
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out [this](https://pythex.org) website which helps test regex patterns for python.

Comment: You need `(?<!\d)(?:[89]|1[0-3])/(?:[0-9]|1[0-5])(?!\d)`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! That works.  Now I just have to continue reading the documentation to fully understand what is going on with the ? and !.  :)

Comment: If you think a '/' might interfere with user input, it would also be reasonable to add two `input()` calls, one for the slot, and then one for the port. Remembering to include a `/` is probably not as important to you as the two numbers.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It's trivially easy to do this using `str.split()` and then parsing the resulting strings into integers.

Comment: You are correct.  I had a working module using str.split(), but I needed to make a module that would be able to take multiple entries at once, such as (8/0 9/15 11/12), as well as making sure the module would ignore errors or wrong responses.  This is why I wanted to use regex so I could achieve this goad without writing too much additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is not well-formed, as you utilized square brackets where round brackets must be. `[8-9|1[0-3]` and `[0-9|1[0-5]` both are bad patterns as `[8-9` and `[0-9` are not closed character classes.

Use

```js
\b(?:[89]|1[0-3])/(?:[0-9]|1[0-5])\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/TyHmDn/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [89]                     any character of: '8', '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-3]                    any character of: '0' to '3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great great response!  Sorry that I took so long to answer, I wasn't aware that the question was reopened.  Using the boundary really made a huge difference, since I wanted to ensure that useless input such as c8/9 would be ignored.  I have marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are using requires 1's on both sides of the "/", use the "|" symbol to imply OR statements such that there is a choice of "a or "b", "a|b". This would give you a regex more in line with "[8-9]|1[0-3]" for before the "/" and "[0-9]|1[0-5]" after. So in total, when using "(regex)" to group parts you want to be expressed separately, you could end up with a regex more inline with "([8-9]|1[0-3])/([0-9]|1[0-5])".

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Yes, it helped me a lot, thanks for responding. My problem was not understanding how to properly group the different subpatterns in order to get the desired result.